# Optionally redirect all requests in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack

I have a requirement where one self-hosted instance X optionally handles a request by redirecting it to another self-hosted instance Y on a different machine. Instance X is authenticated against instance Y. It will do the redirection if there is a header "do_redirect". Is there a mechanism that can do this for all autowired services?

I considered extending all endpoints with an interface and handle the redirect per case basis instead of a request header.

```
public interface IRedirectRequest {
    string ServerUrl {get; set;}
}

[Route("/api/example", "GET")]
public class ExampleRoute : IRedirectRequest, IReturn<string>
{
   //......
}
```

but I have over a hundred enpoints to that is unfeasable.
I also tried a global request filter but I learned since I can't write to the response dto directly.

```
GlobalRequestFilters.Add((request, response, dto) =>
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Headers["do_redirect"]))
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(serverYUrl)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(apiKey, "")

        };
        // redirect here
        var redirectResponse = client.Send(dto.GetType(), dto);
        // terminate request with data from the other server
        response.Dto = redirectResponse;
        response.EndRequest();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a [Generic Proxy](http://docs.servicestack.net/http-utils#creating-a-proxy-using-http-utils) not a redirect, which you can implement with something like:

```
[Route("/proxy")]
public class Proxy : IRequiresRequestStream, IReturn<string>
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}

public object Any(Proxy request)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Url))
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Url");

    var hasRequestBody = base.Request.Verb.HasRequestBody();
    try
    {
        var bytes = request.Url.SendBytesToUrl(
          method: base.Request.Verb,
          requestBody: hasRequestBody ? request.RequestStream.ReadFully() : null,
          contentType: hasRequestBody ? base.Request.ContentType : null,
          accept: ((IHttpRequest)base.Request).Accept,
          requestFilter: req => req.UserAgent = "Gistlyn",
          responseFilter: res => base.Request.ResponseContentType = res.ContentType);

        return bytes;
    }
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response;
        base.Response.StatusCode = (int)errorResponse.StatusCode;
        base.Response.StatusDescription = errorResponse.StatusDescription;
        var bytes = errorResponse.GetResponseStream().ReadFully();
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Where every request sent to `/proxy?url={URL}` will be proxied to that URL. You'll also want to disable:

```
SetConfig(new HostConfig {
    SkipFormDataInCreatingRequest = true
});
```

Which can interfere with accessing the Request Body in your Proxy implementation above.